# show r squared, aic, bic, and deviance for multiple models using gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

looking to have the r squared, aic, bic, and deviance values presented for each of the four models here in the merged output

```
mod0 <- lm(surv_time ~ Age + Gender + Education + `Standardized MoCA`, data = surv_tbldata_converters)
mod1 <- lm(surv_time ~ Age + Gender + Education + `Global Composite`, data = surv_tbldata_converters)

mod2 <- lm(surv_time ~ Age + Gender + Education + `Standardized MoCA`, data = surv_tbldata)
mod3 <- lm(surv_time ~ Age + Gender + Education + `Global Composite`, data = surv_tbldata)

mod0_tbl <- mod0 %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = F) %>%
  add_glance_source_note(include = c(r.squared, AIC, BIC, deviance))

mod1_tbl <- mod1 %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = F) %>%
  add_glance_source_note(include = c(r.squared, AIC, BIC, deviance))

mod2_tbl <- mod2 %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = F) %>%
  add_glance_source_note(include = c(r.squared, AIC, BIC, deviance))

mod3_tbl <- mod3 %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = F) %>%
  add_glance_source_note(include = c(r.squared, AIC, BIC, deviance))

# merge tables 
tbl_merge(tbls = list(mod2_tbl, mod3_tbl, mod0_tbl, mod1_tbl),
          tab_spanner = c("**MoCA Model (Full Sample)**", "**Global Composite Model (Full Sample)**", "**MoCA Model (Converters Only)**", "**Global Composite Model (Converters Only)**")) %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Predictor**") %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 3. Study One Model Comparisons**")  %>%
  bold_labels()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `add_glance_source_note()` function adds the statistics as a source note, and the table may only have one source note. Use the `add_glance_table()` function to add the statistics to the bottom of the table, and you'll be able to merge the tables without issue. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.1'

lm1 <- lm(age ~ trt + grade, trial) 
lm2 <- lm(marker ~ trt + grade, trial)

tbl1 <-
  tbl_regression(lm1) %>%
  add_glance_table(include = c(r.squared, AIC, BIC, deviance))
tbl2 <-
  tbl_regression(lm2) %>%
  add_glance_table(include = c(r.squared, AIC, BIC, deviance))


tbl_all <- tbl_merge(list(tbl1, tbl2))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @daniel ! This mostly answered my question. However, because I am comparing non-nested models (i.e., lm1 <- lm(age ~ trt + grade, trial) vs. lm2 <- lm(age ~ trt + gender, trial)), using add_glance_table  with tbl_regression (followed by tbl_merge) results in the predictor in the second model (gender in this example) being presented in a row BELOW the statistic value rows added by add_glance_table. Hopefully this makes sense as stack overflow won't let me add a picture with my comment.

Comment: Check out the Tips Section of the help file. It has an example on how to preserve the ordering in the table. http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_glance.html